# How to inject a file as a property in Spring XML bean definition

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to inject the file in the XML bean definition to use it from its structure instead of it checking in the jar files.

I have a file which is in the webapp directory like Webapp/ui/page/123.html and wanted to access the same.

I gave the XML entry as below

```
<property name="resourceEntry">
    <value type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource">classpath:/ui/page/123.html</value>
</property>
```

But on accessing the application, it says file not found.

Note: If this file is part of any of the Jar in the Webapp, then it is working.

Any ideas or suggestions

Comment: You gave an absolute path: `classpath:/ui/page/123.html`. Try it with `classpath*:ui/page/123.html`

Comment: @uweAllner I tried the same way and see the below error

'Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:ui/page/123.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist'

Comment: And the file has definitely been deployed in this location?

Comment: @UweAllner, yes it is deployed in the location. But as i informed on the original post, the html file is UI Structure like **webapp/ui** and the spring is calling from a different location which is from **webapp/web-inf/lib** folder

Comment: Then the webapp folder itself probably is not part of the classpath.

Comment: that is what my original question is, whether it will be picked or not